# regular expression matches returning false

Tags: java, regex

The below code is executing fine and I am able to get all the values, but matcher.matches() is returning false.

```
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)").matcher("(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)");

System.out.println("Matches: " + matcher.matches());
int index = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {            
    point[index] = new Point(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)), Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2)));
    index++;
}
```

can anyone please tell me why matcher.matches() is returning false

Comment: sorry its my mistake, even if we give` (8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)` it is giving false

Comment: Matches requires the whole string to match.

Comment: how can I validate the whole string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try matching using this regex: `^\(-?\d+,-?\d+\)(,\s*\(-?\d+,-?\d+\)){3}$`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\)(\\s*,\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\)){3}$");

// this will match
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)");
System.out.println("Matches: " + matcher.matches());

// this will not match
matcher = pattern.matcher("(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1");
System.out.println("Matches: " + matcher.matches());

// neither will this one, which has a dangling comma
matcher = pattern.matcher("(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),");
System.out.println("Matches: " + matcher.matches());

// neither will this one, which has too few order pairs
matcher = pattern.matcher("(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2)");
System.out.println("Matches: " + matcher.matches());

// neither will this one, which has too many order pairs
matcher = pattern.matcher("(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1),(3,-5)");
System.out.println("Matches: " + matcher.matches());
```

Comment: matcher.find() is now not executing

Comment: @AlexMan Updated my answer it should be working for you now.

Comment: Use this Java regex: `\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\)(,\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\))*$`

Comment: matcher.find() is now not executing

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to _validate_ the string, or extract from it?  To extract, just use `matcher.group()`

Comment: I want to print all the values too after validating

Comment: @Alex I added a check for optional spaces.

Answer (score 2):

`matches` return true only if the whole String matches the whole regular expression.

For your case, only part of the String matches the regular expression

i.e. `(8,0)` matches the regular expression but not the whole string

Answer (score 1):

`matches` requires the whole string to match, so you need to repeat your pattern:

```
"(\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\), )*\\((-?\\d+),(-?\\d+)\\)"
```

Which is:

```
(pattern, )*pattern
```

So it will match one or more coordinates, separated by comma space.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible to use match groups in repeating groups. Only the first and last group will be matched.
But you can first check if the string matches a regex without capturing groups and then split up the string on your own.

```
final String coords = "(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)";

if (coords.matches("\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\)(?:, ?\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\))*")) {
    final String[] splitted = coords.replaceAll(" |\\(|\\)", "").split(",");
    final Point[] points = new Point[splitted.length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i += 2) {
        points[i / 2] = new Point(Integer.parseInt(splitted[i]), Integer.parseInt(splitted[i + 1]));
    }
}
```

Since you don't know how many coordinates are given in the string you should use a `List` to store the extracted `Point`s.

```
final String coords = "(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)";
final List<Point> points = new ArrayList<>();

if (coords.matches("\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\)(?:, ?\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\))*")) {
    final String[] splitted = coords.replaceAll(" |\\(|\\)", "").split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; i += 2) {
        points.add(new Point(Integer.parseInt(splitted[i]), Integer.parseInt(splitted[i + 1])));
    }
}
```

Comment: if we input `(8,0), (0,-1), (7,-2), (1,1)` instead of `(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)` it is failing

Comment: how can we put optional too

Comment: You did not specify that you also want to match comma space separated lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following regex :

```
((^|,)\(-?\d+,-?\d+\))+$
```

Here is an example :

```
String str = "(8,0),(0,-1),(7,-2),(1,1)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((^|,)\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\))+$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

Output :

```
true
```

Or you can just use :

```
str.matches("((^|,)\\(-?\\d+,-?\\d+\\))+$");
```